# How can i not get a syntax error for my boolean variable?

Tags: python

I am creating a snake game on the sense hat and i was trying to make my snake grow every time it ate a food.

I made a boolean variable called remove so that when remove is True it would add a pixel on the back of my snake. But whenever i try to run my code, it showed syntax error and i have no idea why this is happening

```
def move():
  global score
  last = snake[-1]
  first = snake[0]
  next = list(last)
  remove = True

  if direction == "right":
    if last[0] + 1 == 8:
     next[0] = 0
    else:
     next[0] = last[0] + 1
  elif direction == "left":
    if last[0] - 1 == -1: 
      next[0] = 7
    else:
      next[0] = last[0] - 1

  elif direction == "down":
    if last[1] + 1 == 8: 
      next[1] = 0
    else:
      next[1] = last[1] + 1

  elif direction == "up":
    if last[1] - 1 == -1: 
      next[1] = 7
    else:
      next[1] = last[1] - 1

  if next in vegetables: 
    vegetables.remove(next)
    score += 1

  if remove = True:
    sense.set_pixel(first[0], first[1], blank)
    slug.remove(first)
    if next in vegetables:
      if score % 1 == 0:
        remove = False
        pause = pause * 8

  snake.append(next)
  sense.set_pixel(next[0], next[1], green)
  sense.set_pixel(first[0], first[1], blank)
  snake.remove(first)
```

This is supposed to make my snake become longer but it just shows an error.

Comment: Please include the complete error message in your question.

Comment: You meant `if remove == True:` instead of `if remove = True:`, but that should simply be `if remove:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
if remove = True:
    sense.set_pixel(first[0], first[1], blank)
```

Should be:

```
if remove == True:
    sense.set_pixel(first[0], first[1], blank)
```

Or better yet:

```
if remove:
    sense.set_pixel(first[0], first[1], blank)
```

Comment: This did get rid of the error but it still doesn't seem to add a new pixel behind my snake. Do you see the problem in my code?

Comment: @RyanBae I'd advice you to make a new question for that :) also feel free to mark this answer as accepted if you feel like it answered this question.